# Upgrading from the old setVersion of indexedDB to the new indexedDB.open function?

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb

This is the only example of a form submission using IndexedDB that a could find but it only works on chrome because of the old setVersion function, I have been trying to get it to work but I´m new to Javascript and IndexedDB. Could somebody give me a hand in reverting it to work in Firefox too?
Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset=iso-8859-1>
<script>
var DB_NAME = 'DBforms';
var STORE_NAME = 'Form';    
var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB    || window.msIndexedDB;

if (window.indexedDb) {
} else if (window.webkitIndexedDB) {
    window.indexedDB = window.webkitIndexedDB;
    window.IDBTransaction = window.webkitIDBTransaction;
} else if (window.mozIndexedDB) {
    window.indexedDB = window.mozIndexedDB;
} else {
   alert("Browser does not suport HTML5´s IndexedDB!");
}       

function onUnexpectedError(e) { alert('An error as occured: ' + e.value); }

function openStore(db, callback) {
    var transaction = db.transaction(STORE_NAME, IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
    var store = transaction.objectStore(STORE_NAME);
    callback(store);
        function saveRow(store, row) {
    var key = new Date().getTime();
    var request = store.put(row, key);
    request.onsuccess = function() {
        alert('Form was saved');
    };
    request.onerror = onUnexpectedError;
}

function isOthergender() {
    return document.form.gender.selectedIndex == document.form.gender.length-1;
}

function saveRecord() {
    // get parameters from the form to build the record
    var gender, name, lastname, email, phone, observations, username;
    if (isOthergender())
        gender = document.form.other.value;
    else
gender = document.form.gender.options[document.form.gender.selectedIndex].value;
    name = document.form.name.value;
    lastname = document.form.lastname.value;
    email = document.form.email.value;
    phone = document.form.phone.value;
    observations = document.form.observations.value;
    username = document.form.username.value;
    var record = {'gender': gender, 'name': name, 'lastname': lastname, 'email': email, 'phone': phone, 'observations': observations, 'username': username};

**// This is what needs to be changed**
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
// open db
var openDbRequest = indexedDB.open(DB_NAME);
openDbRequest.onsuccess = function (e) {
   var db = e.target.result;
   db.onerror = onUnexpectedError;

   if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains(STORE_NAME)) {     


   function createStore(db, callback) {
      var request = db.setVersion('1.0'); // setVersion tx req'd to createObjectStore

      request.onsuccess = function() {
             var store = db.createObjectStore(STORE_NAME);
         callback(store); // this executes in the setVersion tx
       };
       request.onerror = onUnexpectedError;
    }       

      // create db store and save form as row keyed by date
      createStore(db, saveRowCallback);
    } else {
     // open db store and save form as row keyed by date
     openStore(db, saveRowCallback);
    }


    function saveRowCallback(store) {
    saveRow(store, record);
    };

};

openDbRequest.onerror = function () {
alert('Allow access to IndexedDB for this webpage!');
};      
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------

function enableOther() {
    if (isOthergender()) {
        document.form.other.disabled = false;
        document.form.other.value = 'what other?';
    } else {
        document.form.other.disabled = true;
        document.form.other.value = '';
    }
}


</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form">
    <table>
        <tr><td>
        <label>Gender</label>
        <select name="gender" onchange="enableOther()">
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
            <option value="Bot">Bot</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td><input name="other" disabled="true"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><label>Name</label><input name="name" value="" size="10" maxlength="20"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><label>Last Name</label><input name="lastname" value="" size="10" maxlength="20"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><label>Email</label><input name="email" value="" size="10" maxlength="20"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><label>Phone number</label><input name="phone"/></td></tr><tr/>
<tr><td><label>Observations</label></td></tr><textarea name="observations" rows="3" cols="25" wrap="soft"></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td><label>UserName</label><input name="username" value="" size="10" maxlength="20"/></td></tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" name="save" value="Save" onclick="saveRecord()"/>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>
</form>     
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the console.log messages in firefox, use the firebug extension.  Then this should at least get you started:

Get rid of `function openStore`.

```
var openDbRequest = indexedDB.open(DB_NAME, 1);
openDbRequest.onerror = function (e) { console.log("error " + e); }
openDbRequest.onblocked = function (e) { console.log("blocked " + e); }
openDbRequest.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {
  var db = e.target.result;
  db.createObjectStore(STORE_NAME);
  var transaction = e.target.transaction;
  transaction.oncomplete = transaction.onabort = function(e) { console.log("transaction result: " + e); }
}
openDbRequest.onsuccess = function (e) {
  var db = e.target.result;
  if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains(STORE_NAME))
    console.log(STORE_NAME + " didn't exist, weird");
  var transaction = db.transaction(STORE_NAME, IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
  var store = transaction.objectStore(STORE_NAME);
  var key = new Date().getTime();
  var request = store.put(row, key);
  request.onsuccess = function(e) { console.log("onsuccess"); }
  request.onerror = function(e) { console.log("onerror"); }
  transaction.oncomplete = function(e) { console.log("oncomplete"); }
  transaction.onabort = function(e) { console.log("onabort"); }
};
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT Dangerz!
Working perfect, I've just substituted the object "row" for the object "record" in the function - "var request = store.put(row, key);"
it's now - "var request = store.put(record, key);" and it's working fine.
praise the community, and thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try using het the following [shim](https://gist.github.com/2656808). This means also you need to loose everything with the setVersion in your code, and you need to provide a version argument in the open method on the indexeddb

Comment: Hi Kristof, first of all thanks for your answer, I'm trying to avoid wrappings and shims for the manipulation of IndexedDB, I'm building an app that wont be done any time soon... so I prefer to wait till the the final spec is adopted by all browsers.
Anyway congratulations for your work on IndexedDB, I've been following your blog and picking some good ideas and tips, great job and thanks a lot!
Cheers from Portugal

Comment: I'm afraid it will still take a while before all browsers will adopt the final spec. (it's even final yet). But you can always use one of the several available frameworks for building your app. Some of them even provide extra functionality on top of cross browser compatibility.